# How to simultaneously sort 2 lists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists `{ 7 3 5 }` and `{9 8 1}`.

I want to sort my first list and I want the second list to have the same index permutation as given by the first list.

`{3 5 7}` => `{8 1 9}`

Is it possible to do this in a single LINQ statement?

Comment: So, to make sure I'm clear, you want to sort the first list, and have the second list sort by that key as well?

Comment: Darn it, Jon beat me to it...  Zip is handy for that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sounds like you might want:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 7, 3, 5 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 9, 8, 1 };

var orderedZip = list1.Zip(list2, (x, y) => new { x, y } )
                      .OrderBy(pair => pair.x)
                      .ToList();
list1 = orderedZip.Select(pair => pair.x).ToList();
list2 = orderedZip.Select(pair => pair.y).ToList();
```

Comment: How is it possible to answer this question in 68 seconds?

Comment: @Aidan, Because he's Jon Skeet, 'nuff said... :-)

Comment: He's like the Chuck Norris of SO

Comment: @Aidan: Hah!  Sounds like a good line of jokes... Jon Skeet doesn't need to sort lists, when Jon Skeet arrives they sort themselves.

Comment: @Aidan: I've always had a suspicion that Jon has something in the SO code that de;ays posts by 5 minutes for everybody except him... :)

Comment: It's an honor to be beaten to a response by Jon Skeet.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: LOL ... :D

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: By comparison, in constant time.

Comment: @Aducci  Jon Skeet's one of several high rep users who I think are disproportionately likely to be upvoted.  I suspect it's a mix a of hero worship and "I don't understand this, but X is always right so I'll give him an up vote anyway".

Answer (score 10):

You could try using the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method:

```
var sortedPairs = list1
    .Zip(list2, (item1, item2) => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(item1, item2))
    .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key);
```

Then you could get the first sorted list by:

```
var sortedList1 = sortedPairs.Select(pair => pair.Key);
```

And the second list by:

```
var sortedList2 = sortedPairs.Select(pair => pair.Value);
```